# How do I get this text using Jsoup?

Tags: java, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

How do i get "this text" from the following html code using Jsoup?

```
<h2 class="link title"><a href="myhref.html">this text<img width=10 
        height=10 src="img.jpg" /><span class="blah">
        <span>Other texts</span><span class="sometime">00:00</span></span>
        </a></h2>
```

When I try

```
String s = document.select("h2.title").select("a[href]").first().text();
```

it returns

> this textOther texts00:00

I tried to read the api for [Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) in Jsoup but could not figure out much.

Also how do i get an element of class `class="link title blah"` (multiple classes?). Forgive me I only know both Jsoup and CSS a little.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Element#ownText()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29) instead of [`Element#text()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29).

```
String s = document.select("h2.link.title a[href]").first().ownText();
```

Note that you can select elements with multiple classes by just concatenating the classname selectors together like as `h2.link.title` which will select `<h2>` elements which have at least *both* the `link` and `title` class.

Comment: Also how do i get an element of class `class="link title blah" (multiple classes)?

Comment: Check the code example closely. I have added explanation to the answer afterwards.