# Jsoup returns wrong ChildNode

Tags: parsing, jsoup

I would Like to parse the Metadata to a Book. Whild trying to retrieve the Booktitle, I noticed I can't access the ChildNodes from an Element that contains a TextNode. Here is my Data:

```
<div id="detail_content_wrapper">

                <h1>
                    MyBookTitle 22<br>

                    <span class="sub">

                        subtext
                                                     Book 22
                        by <a href="/buch-autor/foo-bar">Foo Bar</a>
                    </span>

                </h1>
```

I retrieve the Elements within "detail_content_wrapper"  using:

```
Document parsedObject = Jsoup.parse(source);
Element bookNotes = parsedObject.getElementById("detail_content_wrapper");
Element h1Element = bookNotes.getElementsByTag("h1").first()
```

This will give me the complete content inside the h1-Tag.

When I take a look at the h1-Element ChildNodes, the first Childnode is a TextNode that holds the BookName. BUT when I try to get the Content of the First Child...

```
 Element bookName = h1Element.children().first();
```

OR   `Element bookName = h1Element.childNode(0);`

...This will, in both cases, contain the 2nd node which is the br-Element.

Is this a bug or am I using Jsoup wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get this text using Jsoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417295/how-do-i-get-this-text-using-jsoup)

Comment: Thanks mate. I got it fixed by using the ownText() method. But we shouldn't close this thread until  the behavior of the childNode-Method is clear. It is not possible to access the ChildNode containing the TextNode, as fas as I can see.